# Is there a nice way to access properties of a nested control in xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, nested

in my Application i got a listbox containing nested controls.
Is there a way to access the properties of a nested control?

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
    <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=mylistbox,Path=SelectedItem???}"></Label>
    <ListBox x:Name="mylistbox">
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Button >
                <TextBox x:Name="testbox" Text="number 1">
                    
                </TextBox>
            </Button>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Button>
                <TextBox x:Name="testbox2" Text="number 2">

                </TextBox>
            </Button>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here I would like to display the text of the selected textbox in the label. Maybe this is possible with selectedValuePath or a special Path syntax?

Comment: Instead of declaring multiple identical ListBoxItems in XAML, declare a DataTemplate as the ListBox's ItemTemplate and bind the ListBox's ItemsSource property to a collection of data items. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview). Besides that, a TextBox in a Button makes no sense at all. Maybe you just want to bind the Button's Content property to a property of the data item.

Comment: Thats only a small nonsense example. In my Application a listbox collects some nested controls from different views. The nested controls holds some data which i want to access. But with selectedValuePath i can only access the rootcontrol.

Comment: Try to explain as precisely as possible what exactly "*a listbox collects some nested controls from different views*" is supposed to mean.

Comment: Sry thats my first question. My listbox´s itemsource is a list of own usercontrols. The Usercontrol contains some other controls like textblocks( lets call him textblock1). I want to access the nested controls of the Usercontrol. If i select an item in the listbox i want to display the text of the nested textblock(textblock1).

Comment: That's the wrong approach in the first place. Declare the UserControl in the ItemTemplate and bind its properties (or the properties of the elements in its XAML) to the data item object in the ItemsSource collection.